# python: can't open file 'lanes.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv

I am learning OpenCV python and I am watching this YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLTLtUVuuy4&t=45s) of "finding lanes for self-driving cars".

At 10:24 of the video, this person opens a command and types `python lanes.py`.

If I do the same thing,
the command says

> "python: can't open file 'lanes.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory"

Does anyone know how to fix this? Please do not hesitate to answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Keigo. You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a file named `lanes.py` in the current directory.

Either you never created it, or you created it with the wrong name, or you're in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have downloaded the tutorial files, make sure that your terminal is in the same directory as the file you want to open.

e.g. If lanes.py is in the folder /Downloads/Python

Then run `cd /Downloads/Python` to change directory (cd) before you start.

Then you should be able to type your command as:

`$: /Downloads/Python>` python lanes.py

(or similar, depending on your os)